# Is there a way to synchronize a webpage from another website into Drupal?

Tags: nodes, javascript, 9

A restaurant has its menu database in [Foodpanda](https://www.foodpanda.co.th/).

The owner wants that menu to appear in the website.

- We can manually duplicate all menu courses from FoodPanda to Drupal, upload the same images, etc. each menu course as a standalone node of a *menu* content type and then add some module for purchasing courses from the website (as delivery).
- We might also be able to move the database from FoodPanda to a more "agnostic" menu as a service app such as *Delivery Hero* or *Deliverect* and then synchronize both Foodpanda and Drupal from there

But, it might be much better to somehow embed the menu webpage from Foodpanda into the website; the user would visit a node "menu" but the content of that node would be the menu webpage in Foodpanda, for example, [embedding this entire webpage as is](https://www.foodpanda.co.th/restaurant/t4hj/saras-sukhumvit-20), in the "menu" webpage in Drupal; can this be done elegantly somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here.

1. You can use a standard `<iframe>`.  To use the `<iframe>` tag, you may need to adjust the text forms and editor settings at `/admin/config/content/formats`.
2. You can use the [Iframe](https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe) module.  This creates a field that you can add to your node content type, and then you can add iFrames to each piece of content by entering a value for this field. In your case, since it's only one page, using a module like this is probably overkill, but it provides some nice options in the UI like how big to make the iframe, so your client may want this feature.
3. You can just add a Drupal menu link directly to Foodpanda; Drupal allows you to put off-site menu links in menus.